# How to add multiple paths for phpcs?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, phpcs

I want to configure multiple installed paths for `phpcs`.

I can add one via:

`phpcs --config-set installed_paths the/dir/to/standard`

I tried adding multiple by using `:` yet it did not work and the man page is non-existent and the help not that helpful.

Comment: Docs are here: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki , and the specific doc you need is here: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Configuration-Options#setting-the-installed-standard-paths

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use a comma-separated list without spaces between the paths:

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths first/path/,second/path/,yet/another/path/
```

Comment: Just to note, on Windows I put quotations around the paths as some had spaces in them. For e.g. `phpcs --config-set installed_paths "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drupal\coder\coder_sniffer,C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\something\else\here"`

Comment: Using `$(pwd)` 

worked for me (WordPress and CodeIgniter):


`~ phpcs --config-set installed_paths $(pwd)/.composer/codeigniter4-standard,$(pwd)/.composer/wpcs`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same frustration about not being able to set multiple paths. I use a bash script to append the current path to the installed_paths:

`phpcs_ipath=$(phpcs --config-show installed_paths); oldpath=${phpcs_ipath##*:}; phpcs --config-set installed_paths ${oldpath},$(pwd)`

I `cd` into the directory that contains my new standards, then run this one-liner. It grabs the current paths and appends the current path to them. Not perfect, but it's a quick way to add paths.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using a comma (`,`) as a separator, if you're on a Unix shell, do not use `~/...`. Use `$HOME/...` or use the actual path (e.g. `/home/nabil/...`).

#### `~/...` won't work

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths ~/path_1,~/path_2
```

#### `$HOME/...` or the actual path (e.g. `/home/nabil/...`) will work

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths $HOME/path_1,$HOME/path_2
```

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths /home/nabil/path_1,/home/nabil/path_2
```